# Pig View Not Opening

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform

In the Ambari UI of the hortonworks sandbox, I was trying to open Hive View through the default account of maria_dev. But however, I was getting the following error:

```
500 Unable to read database password
```

The following output was displayed in `trace` :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read database password

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read database password
    at org.apache.ambari.server.configuration.Configuration.readPasswordFromFile(Configuration.java:3965)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.configuration.Configuration.getDatabasePassword(Configuration.java:3927)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.view.persistence.DataStoreModule.getEntityManagerFactory(DataStoreModule.java:128)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.view.persistence.DataStoreModule.<init>(DataStoreModule.java:81)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.view.ViewContextImpl.getDataStore(ViewContextImpl.java:332)
    at org.apache.ambari.view.pig.persistence.DataStoreStorage.loadAll(DataStoreStorage.java:80)
    at org.apache.ambari.view.pig.resources.CRUDResourceManager.readAll(CRUDResourceManager.java:78)
    at org.apache.ambari.view.pig.resources.scripts.ScriptService.getScriptList(ScriptService.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1507)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.security.authorization.AmbariAuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AmbariAuthorizationFilter.java:287)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.security.authentication.AmbariDelegatingAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AmbariDelegatingAuthenticationFilter.java:132)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.security.authorization.AmbariUserAuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AmbariUserAuthorizationFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.api.MethodOverrideFilter.doFilter(MethodOverrideFilter.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.api.AmbariPersistFilter.doFilter(AmbariPersistFilter.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.view.AmbariViewsMDCLoggingFilter.doFilter(AmbariViewsMDCLoggingFilter.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.view.ViewThrottleFilter.doFilter(ViewThrottleFilter.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.security.AbstractSecurityHeaderFilter.doFilter(AbstractSecurityHeaderFilter.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.security.AbstractSecurityHeaderFilter.doFilter(AbstractSecurityHeaderFilter.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariHandlerList.processHandlers(AmbariHandlerList.java:212)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariHandlerList.processHandlers(AmbariHandlerList.java:201)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariHandlerList.handle(AmbariHandlerList.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:973)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1035)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:641)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File '/etc/ambari-server/conf/password.dat' does not exist
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openInputStream(FileUtils.java:265)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(FileUtils.java:1457)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(FileUtils.java:1475)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.configuration.Configuration.readPasswordFromFile(Configuration.java:3962)
    ... 101 more
```

I feel that the error is in the file `/etc/ambari-server/conf/password.dat` that is missing. But since I am new to the hadoop ecosystem, I am unable to sort out as in where and how to add this file so as to open up the `Pig View`.

Can someone please help me sort out the error ? I did enough googling, but to no help.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same question on community.hortonworks.com. I got a solution there which worked just fine for me. 
I ran the following commands and checked if you are able to open Pig view

```
echo "bigdata" > /etc/ambari-server/conf/password.dat
ambari-server restart
```

This worked like a cakewalk. :)